# How do I ensure both my objects have loaded before I render the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase

I have a react app using firebase as my database. I am trying to load 2 separate objects and display their info on the page, problem is that only the "user" loads and is shown, but if I reload the page, the rest shows up so its loading but not on the initial rendering. Is there a way to make it work without manually reloading the page?

The code I currently have for the render is this one:

```
const [ dadosCarregados, setDadosCarregados ] = useState(false);
  const { retrieveUser, getUserSheets, user, list } = useRetrieveDatabase()

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveUser(userId).then(
      getUserSheets(userId).then(
        setDadosCarregados(true)
      )
    )
  }, [dadosCarregados])
  
  if(!user) {
    return <p>Carregando...</p>
  }

  return (//the loaded page)
```

the hooks that get the data are the following:

```
const retrieveUser = async (userId) => {
        checkIfIsCancelled()
        setLoading(true)

        try {
            const userDocRef = doc(collection(db, 'usuarios'), userId)
            const userDocSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef)

            if (userDocSnapshot.exists()) {
                setUser(userDocSnapshot.data())
            } else {
                console.log('Usuario não encontrado')
            }
        
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Erro ao buscar usuário: ' + error)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    const getUserSheets = async (userId) => {
        checkIfIsCancelled()
        setLoading(true)

        try {
            const sheetsQuery = query(collection(db, 'fichas'), where('Idcriador', '==', userId));
            const sheetsQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(sheetsQuery);

            const userSheets = sheetsQuerySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
            setList(userSheets);
        
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Erro: ' + error)
            return []
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }
```

I've tried making the two functions one, but it didn't work. I also tried putting "dadosCarregados" and "list" on the if, but it ended up in an error. What else could I do?

Comment: I don't know if it will help but it will make the code clearer. Have you tried using async/await for the `userEffect`?

```
useEffect(async () => {
    await retrieveUser(userId);
    await getUserSheets(userId);
    await setDadosCarregados(true);
  }, [dadosCarregados])
```

Comment: In addition, why are you doing them serially and not in parallel? Like this:
```
useEffect(async () => {
    await Promise.all([retrieveUser(userId), getUserSheets(userId), setDadosCarregados(true)]);
  }, [dadosCarregados])
```

Comment: I'm asking these questions to try to understand the motives and need to better help you :)

Comment: I'm a beginner actually, I didn't know I could do it like that, I'll try that. Also, about the async I tried something similar but it didn't work, I think I did put an async function inside the useeffect, but it itself wasn't, gonna also try that. Thanks for the comments!